# Pathfinding algorithm in an unweighted graph with no loops

Tags: graph-theory, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search, dijkstra, path-finding

I'm searching an algorithm to find the best path between two nodes in a unweighted graph, with no loops and each node can reach only nodes greater than him (the ID is an int), that has the least nodes in it.

I've searched online and I found that the Breadth First Search algorithm can be used for pathfinding.
Is it good in term of speed and time?
I tried with Depth First Search, and when i found the "end" node the code decided based on the length of the path, to substitute or not the stored path.
But I realized that with that method it takes too much time, comparing every single possible path and choosing if its better or worse than the one stored.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Please clarify this " each node can reach only nodes greater than him (the ID is an int), that has the least nodes in it."  A small example would help a lot.

Comment: Is your graph directed or undirected?

Comment: If a node has the num attribute = 10, it can reach only nodes that have the num greater than the original node (i.e. nodes with node num = 11, 12, 13, ...)

Comment: Please edit your question so that is is clear.

Comment: "that has the least nodes in it." ??????????

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use BFS since your graph is unweighted.  But first you have to handle your ID restriction on reachabe nodes.

Like this:

**for Directed graph**

- Remove all links between nodes where the source cannot reach the destination because of the ID restriction
- Apply BFS

**for UnDirected Graph**

- Replace all links with two directed links, one going each way between link endpoints
- Apply BFS

Comment: How could the graph ever be undirected? (BTW, good you updated the answer and removed the reference to Dijkstra's algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

Breadth first search is indeed the right choice for an unweighted graph.

It can be implemented with a queue (FIFO) or with two arrays, where in each iteration of the loop you collect the unvisited neighbors of the nodes in the first array into an empty second array, and then assign the second array to the first before repeating the procedure again.